# jQuery Video and Image Gallery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a gallery to my site.Please suggest me a good jQuery for that.I have tried with several but doesn't work for me.I want to add video n images in that gallery.Videos are from you tube.

Comment: There are plenty websites that list libraries to do such things, just google it... SO is not intended for this kind of question. Come back if you cannot make it work when you implement it on your website, but not to choose it

Comment: A damn, Google only has [1.3 million results](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+image+video+gallery) for that question.

Comment: A good jQuery? I suggest 1.10.1

Comment: I want to add both videos and images to that gallery.I want to implement that to facebook so can't use popups.That's why i have posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item">…</div>
<div class="item">…</div>
<div class="item">…</div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

In
  `<div class="item" > </div>`

You can put anything photos and video what ever you want to put.

And after that put your

```
`<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"> `
```

in

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

modal div ....Your gallery is ready ...